# Como pegar o valor de uma ListBox a partir do índice selecionado de outra ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando pegar o valor de uma `ListBox` a partir do índice selecionado de outra `ListBox`, porém não funciona. O que tenho até o presente momento:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Lst_ListBoxA.Add(2 * (3 * i) * 4);
    Lst_ListBoxB.Add(2 * (3 / i) * 4);
}
private void Lst_ListBoxB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Aqui, o usuário seleciona o segundo índice (1).
    string Valor = Lst_ListBoxA.GetItemText(Lst_ListBoxB.SelectedIndex);
    MessageBox.Show(valor);
}
```

O que está sendo retornado, ou mostrado na *MessageBox*, é o índice selecionado da `Lst_ListBoxB`, **1**, e não o valor do índice correspondente da `Lst_ListBoxA`, **24**, qual seria o modo correto de fazê-lo?

Comment: WebForms ou Windows Forms?

Comment: Editei as tags, `winforms`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve estar procurando por algo assim:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Lst_ListBoxA.Items.Add("Item 1A");
   Lst_ListBoxA.Items.Add("Item 1B");
   Lst_ListBoxA.Items.Add("Item 1C");

   Lst_ListBoxB.Items.Add("Item 2A");
   Lst_ListBoxB.Items.Add("Item 2B");
   Lst_ListBoxB.Items.Add("Item 2C");
}

private void Lst_ListBoxB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int i = Lst_ListBoxB.SelectedIndex;
   string Valor = Lst_ListBoxA.Items[i].ToString();
   MessageBox.Show(Valor);
}
```

Isso deverá funcionar para você.

Comment: Então é possível tratar qualquer objeto que tenha uma coleção de itens (ComboBox, ListBox, ListView...) como se fosse um array?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo evento [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), você consegue pegar o *Indice* do `ListBox`.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        listBox1.Items.Add("aluno 1");
        listBox1.Items.Add("aluno 2");
        listBox1.Items.Add("aluno 3");

        listBox2.Items.Add("aluno 1");
        listBox2.Items.Add("aluno 2");
        listBox2.Items.Add("aluno 3");     
}
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int i = listBox1.SelectedIndex; //pegando o index do item selecionado
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = i; //posicionando o outro listbox
        MessageBox.Show(listBox2.Text); //mostrando o valor que ele tá!
}
```

Nesse exemplo carregando os listbox funciona assim.

Referencia

- [ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem a última linha... Vou colocar mais dados na pergunta.

Comment: @Patrick, é essa forma usualmente pelo evento! clico ele já posiciona e mostra o valor!